# Картинка-лого в консоли Linux

Tags: linux, изображения, boot

Никак не могу нагуглить. Каким образом мне реализовать вывод картинки в консоль (fb)?
В поиске обсуждают в основном просмотр картинок через fbi, а мне нужно именно вывести картинку в консоль так, чтобы она была там наравне с остальным выводом. Вот как этот пингвин.
Попробовал что-то типа

```
cat image.bmp > /dev/fb0,
```

но получил артефакты вместо картинки -- формат, видно, не тот (картинка 16-битная).
Или опять скажут, что вопрос не вопрос?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот есть программа, но для старой версии ubuntu, для новой придётся наверно пересобирать из исходников https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+package/fim , хотя ваш кноппикс как раз старый.

Comment: У меня не Knoppix, скриншот из интернета. Просто для иллюстрации взял самый наглядный.

Comment: Но увы, эта штука ОСНОВАНА на утилите fbi, которая у меня уже есть и которая не выводит картинку в стандартный вывод -- она позволяет просматривать, да, но не выводить картинку в консоль наравне с текстом.

Comment: Посмотрел, да все эти утилиты как-то переключают консоль перед показом и после просмотра возвращают старое состояние

Comment: Вообще не уверен, что это возможно. Даже если вывести картинку с помощью cat или вроде того, она потом не будет смещаться по мере заполнения экрана текстом, а будет только "затираться" тем, что "наползет" из текста на нее... По-моему. Правда, не знаю, как там с этим пингвинчиком, я себе лого такое отключил.

Comment: Да, действительно, если и разобраться с форматом, картинка выведенная `cat > /dev/fb0` не смещается вместе с текстом при скроллинге

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нашёл следующее решение.

Сначала надо узнать формат буфера. У многих, в том числе и у меня, это BGRA,
т.е. 4 байта на пиксел и в порядке: синий, зелёный, красный, пустой.

`fbset -i` выдаёт размеры экрана и ширину скан-строки в видеопамяти в байтах в строке "LineLength", может отличаться от ширины экрана * 4 в большую сторону. Делим это число на 4 -- получаем ширину картинки, которую надо подготовить.

Рисуем картинку в GIMPе -- ширина как посчитали, высота может быть любая, включаем альфа-канал.
С помощью инструмента Цвет-Компоненты-Микшер каналов меняем местами красный и синий цвета. Сохраняем в "стандартном" формате "RAW".

Теперь её можно записывать во фреймбуфер с помощью `cat`.

*Недостаток который я не знаю как устранить:*
Драйвер текстовой консоли ничего знать не хочет о том, что вы там делаете с видеопамятью напрямую и считает, что там остались те буквы, что он там нарисовал последний раз, поэтому, при скроллировании, он не будет перерисовывать те места, где буквы по его мнению не должны измениться. Картинка не скроллируется и при переключении виртуальных консолей стирается.

Comment: Да, вот что-то такое в принципе годится. Для того, чтоб первоначальное намерение картинку в текст выводить, нет, но чтобы самодельный скринсейвер для консоли сделать -- вполне.

Comment: Еще, в принципе, cat из рандома в фб имеет проблему: рандом технически бесконечный файл, вот кат и копирует до тех пор, пока место не закончится. Решается dd, которому указывается конкретный блоксайз. После этого можно сделать простенький скринсейвер, который каждую секунду будет копировать новый блок из рандома в фб и таким образом показывать анимированный шум на экране. dd, копирующий с параметрами bs=9999 и count=1 (а не наоборот) -- делает это очень быстро.

Comment: К сожалению утилита `convert` из пакета `ImageMagick` содержит ошибки в части создания файлов формата `bgra`, хотя формат очень простой.