# Возможно ли в С вывести что-нибудь в консоль, не используя stdio.h?

Tags: c, printf

Возможно ли в С вывести что-нибудь в консоль, не используя stdio.h, printf?

Comment: [Но зачем?](https://v1.std3.ru/5b/7f/1433517695-5b7febcb5f64cf7e91cf6c5154e8caf9.jpeg)

Comment: [Да](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450587/is-it-possible-write-to-console-without-stdlibs-c-c)

Comment: а "iostream.h" в С был? Или это уже борланд С так реализовал?

Comment: @pavel, не это чисто плюсовый заголовок, [в Си не было](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

Comment: В Linux ещё можно картинку через фреймбуфер: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460297/130

Answer (score 12):

*stdio.h* - это буферизированная надстройка над базовыми функциями ввода-вывода `read`, `write`, объявленными в *unistd.h*.

```
#include <unistd.h>
write(1, "Hallo!\n", sizeof "Hallo!\n" - 1);
```

Первый аргумент - файловый дескриптор - номер в таблице открытых файлов исполняемой программы. При запуске по стандарту заранее открыты три дескриптора: 0 - стандартный ввод, 1 - стандартный вывод, 2 - стандартный вывод ошибок. В некоторых системах могут быть ещё другие.

`fwrite` из того же *stdio.h*. Работает похожим образом, но через тот же буфер, как и `printf`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
fwrite("Hallo!\n", sizeof "Hallo!\n" - 1, 1, stdout);
```

Хотя она и вызывает `write`, но за счёт буферизации часто оказывается быстрее при записи большого количества данных в файл (при перенаправлении вывода). Безусловно `fwrite` быстрее `printf`, так как последняя ищет в строке форматные последовательности, начинающиеся со знака `%`.

`fputs` и `puts` из *stdio.h* выводят строку, оканчивающуюся нулевым байтом (`'\0'`). Вторая добавляет ещё и символ конца строки и выводит только на стандартный вывод.

```
#include <stdio.h>
fputs("Hallo!\n", stdout);
puts("Hallo!"); // выводит то же самое, что и предыдущая функция
```

По скорости должны быть как `fwrite`, но отличаются способом определения длины строки, поэтому с их помощью невозможно вывести сами нулевые байты. Мои измерения в ubuntu однако показывают, что `puts` почему-то намного медленнее `fputs` и почти как `printf`.

Comment: Является ли этот способ более быстрым, чем printf?

Comment: @kalokusatel Вроде должно быть быстрее, поскольку `printf` всё равно вызовет `write`, но перед этим ещё и просканирует строку насчёт форматных последовательностей типа `%d` и т. д. Однако если вывод перенаправить в файл на диске, буферизированный вывод накопит все вызовы `printf` и др., пока не заполнится буфер, и выведет его одним `write`. Это уменьшит число обращений к системе, и может ускорить программу. Т. е. всё зависит от размеров выводимых данных.

Comment: @kalokusatel: `printf()` печатает в stdio буфер (память), поэтому он может быть гораздо быстрее `write()` (системный вызов), если последний часто с маленьким вводом вызывается. Если у вас вопрос как сделать `printf()` быстрее, то это совсем другой вопрос—по сравнению с реальным I/O (особенно дисковым I/O),  вычисления обычно быстры.

Answer (score 7):

В дополнение к POSIX [`write(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) и Win32 [`WriteConsoleW()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401(v=vs.85).aspx) можно упомянуть [`<conio.h>` функции, которые также позволяют выводить в консоль](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h):

> Библиотечные функции, объявленные в conio.h, весьма различались в
>   зависимости от компилятора. Первоначально реализованные в Microsoft
>   Visual C++ различные функции привязывались напрямую к нескольким
>   первым функциям DOS, связанным с прерыванием 21h. Но библиотека,
>   поставляемая с Turbo C++ и Borland C++, не использует DOS API, а
>   вместо этого напрямую обращается к видеопамяти для вывода информации и
>   использования сигналов прерывания BIOS.

```
#include <conio.h>
putch('A');
```

---

Также (зависит от железа, ОСи) можно выводить символы на экран с помощью прямой манипуляции памяти, которая отображена на видео буфер. Из [книги "Computer Graphics Primer", написанной Mitchell Waite и опубликованной в 1979](http://www.atariarchives.org/cgp/Ch02_Sec03.php):

[image: In memory-mapped video the screen memory is part of regular RAM.]

IBM VGA BIOS ([mode 13h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_13h)) режим предоставляет похожий доступ к видеопамяти как к 320×200 массиву пикселов с 256 цветами.

Обычно между программой и видеопамятью присутствует множество уровней абстракции. На Linux, если X не запущен(или в <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> виртуальной консоли), можно [mmap](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) `/dev/fb0` устройство (Linux framebuffer всего на ступеньку выше работы с видеокартой напрямую—интерфейс предоставляется самим ядром):

```
fbdev = open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);
buffer = mmap(0, screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fbdev, 0);
```

Здесь `buffer`—это массив байтов размером `screensize`, запись в который позволяет рисовать в консоли, например, в режиме 1600x1200 32bpp (`screensize = 1600*1200*32/CHAR_BIT`), чтобы закрасить выбранный пиксель ярко жёлтым (красный+зелёный):

```
buffer[i+0] = 0; // синий
buffer[i+1] = 255; // зелёный 
buffer[i+2] = 255; // красный
buffer[i+3] = 0; // прозрачность
```

Вот пример кода, как квадрат нарисовать в консоли, используя framebuffer: [How to display something on screen through linux framebuffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32082248/4279)

Comment: Самое тут интересное (для меня, конечно) -- как узнать `screensize`?

Comment: @avp по ссылке код, где screensize вычисляется

Comment: Спасибо (не догадался посмотреть -))

Comment: Смущает прозрачность - под фреймбуфером что-то ещё может отображаться?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: врядли. Если это не какой-то специальный device, то можно просто как padding рассматривать.

Answer (score 3):

Для винды: WriteConsole().
Для DOS - формирование кода вызова INT 21 и через передачу управления на него.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
/* для любой linux системы. У меня gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4 */
int main()
{
   int i = system ("ls -al");  // показать файлы текущей директории в тч скрытые
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Borland C++ 3.1:

```
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
  putch('7');
  return 0;
}
```