# C - Неправильный вывод в текстовую видеопамять

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос

Здравствуйте! Имеется следующий C-код, который запускается из assembler'а:

```
asm(".code16");

void kernel_start() {
 char *video_memory = (char*)0xb8000;

 for(int i = 0; i < 80 * 25 * 2; i++) {
  video_memory[i] = 0x21;
  video_memory[i + 1] = 0x0F;
 }
}
```

Данный код должен заполнять экран белыми '!' на черном фоне. Но происходит нечто странное: символы сильно растягиваются, и цвет фона и символов ни черный, ни белый
Вот что получается:
[image: легкое недоразумение]

Ощущение что где-то есть смещение и оттого цвет неверный. Но откуда берется растяжение символов? Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему.

Comment: Почему синий на зеленом - понимаю, цвет 1 на фоне 2 (0x21) но вот почему вопросительный знак, не понимаю. знак должен все таки быть восклицательным. Сделайте в цикле `i+=2` вместо `i++` что бы не затирать то, что вы положили в i+1 на предыдущей итерации. Ну а там уже посмотрите что выйдет ...

Comment: @Mike я ничего не говорил про вопросительный знак. Спасибо вы решили мою проблему.

Comment: Ну он у вас на скриншоте вопросительный ... И это мне не понятно. Неужели после исправления кода он стал восклицательным ?

Comment: @Mike на самом деле на скриншоте '!'. Просто жутко растянутый, не знаете почему?

Comment: Ну у вас 40 символов в строке, видеорежим видимо все таки 40x25. Почему не знаю, там ответом написали что 40x25 как раз стандартный но на сколько я помню, под dos все таки был стандартным 80x25. А экран растянут потому что окно qemu такого размера что бы 80 символов вмещать. И подозреваю, что в момент открытия окна оно рассчитывало что будет 80 символов но в какой то момент видеорежим сменился на 40 символьный

Comment: @Mike я установил режим 80x25 из ассемблера и все стало на свои места. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Не имеет отношения к конкретной проблеме в  вопросе, просто напомнило: [Возможно ли в С вывести что-нибудь в консоль, не используя stdio.h?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/565895/23044)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы цвета были правильными нужно заменить блок итерации в цикле, с i++, на i += 2. Для того чтобы установить режим 80x25 из ассемблера нужно выполнить следующие команды:

```
mov AH, 0x00
mov AL, 0x03

int 0x10
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё правильно это QEMU эмулятор конвертирует цвета и шрифты. В чистом DOS всего
25x40 экран, режимы 25х80, 45х80, 50х80 появились значительно позже и в них тогда надо переключаться специальными командами к BIOS. Как сейчас это сделать к сожалению не знаю.

Comment: Извините, что он конвертирует и как ? Структура видеопамяти для всех текстовых режимов одинакова, символ-цвет. Программа рассчитана на заполнение всего экрана, так что она должна его заполнить вне зависимости от разрешения. Вернее она бы заполнила, если бы в цикле правильно бы велась переменная i и кодом символа 0x21 не затирался бы атрибут предыдущего символа на четных итерациях

Comment: Проблема с растянутостью символов была именно в стандартном режиме 25x80. Проблема с цветом из-за итерация как и сказал @Mike Спасибо!