# Рисунок в консоли на python

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Я хотел бы узнать, как рисовать в консоли на python. Кто не понял о чем я, объясню. Думаю все смотрели железного человека. Там он понатыкал разных кнопочек и взломал экран.Там высветилась консоль, и появилась надпись "Stark" из символов. Или например запускаешь экплойты типа metasploit, а там их эмблема из символов.Может кто подскажет ресурсы какие-либо в инете есть, или примерный алгоритм работы. Спасибо

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8&rlz=1C1PRFE_enRU711RU712&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=Bzw-La7Tl6gBaM%253A%252CKb5fc6wGsCFr6M%252C_&usg=__O3jsokag7Utgx4cmHtKZySO64WE%3D&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYvJKr3LXbAhWICsAKHSyNA_wQ9QEIUDAD#imgrc=2zoRYE05VjHQUM: так?

Comment: `▛▀▀▀▚ ▌   ▐ ▞▀▀▀▚ ▞▀▀▀▚`

Comment: `▙▄▄▄▞ ▌   ▐ ▚▄▄▄▖ ▌   ▐`

Comment: `▌   ▚ ▌   ▐     ▐ ▌   ▐`

Comment: `▌   ▐ ▚▄▄▄▞ ▚▄▄▄▞ ▚▄▄▄▞`

Comment: Не понял вопроса, в чём проблема просто взять и отпечатать нужные символы в нужном порядке?

Comment: связанный вопрос [How to easily print ascii-art text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9632995/4279)

Comment: с помощью asciimatics можно динамические эффекты создавать. [Python. Вывод текста по середине терминала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518707/23044) и [print in terminal in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37051472/4279)

Comment: Ребят ну хотелось бы немного цвета , понимаю что такое врядли существует но может быть все таки есть

Comment: @ВасяПупкин вы пробовали хотя бы на одну ссылку нажать? Результаты цветные по всем ссылкам

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы показывать рисунки в консоли, можно использовать [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics) ([галерея](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics/wiki)):

[image: asciimatics images.py tty session]
Это создаёт рисунки из ASCII символов, используя возможности терминала по работе с цветами, позицией курсора, итд. На Linux можно показывать картинки, используя framebuffer e.g., [fbi](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/fbi.1.html). Ещё см. [Возможно ли в С вывести что-нибудь в консоль, не используя stdio.h?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/566011/23044)

Answer (score 2):

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style

init()

def console_picture():
    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW)
    print("                **    **  ********  **        **            **      ")
    print("               **    **  ********  **        **         **     **   ")
    print("              ********  **        **        **         **      **  ")
    print("             ********  ********  **        **         **      **  ")
    print("            **    **  **        **        **         **      **  ")
    print("           **    **  ********  ********  ********    **    **   ")
    print("          **    **  ********  ********  ********       **      ")

console_picture()
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from colorit import init_colorit, color
from PIL import Image

init_colorit()
x = int(input("Размер: ")) 

image = Image.open(input("Файл с картинкой: "))
image = image.resize((x, x))

for y in range(image.size[1]):
    for x in range(image.size[0]):
        print(color("w", image.getpixel((x, y))), end='')
    print()
```

Попробуйте вот так.
Это конечно не  ASCII но побаловаться с картинками тоже можно

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]