# Как написать в консоли стих?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio

Дали задание, вывести на экран стих «Every hunter wants…» таким образом, чтобы каждый «цвет» начинался с новой строки и соответствующим количеством табуляций.

Где можно найти этот стих на английском?
И как его красиво оформить?

Comment: Возможно, перевод данной подсказки о цветах тоже является частью задания. И, как мне кажется, основной. Потому что вывод в консоль строк - это же как самая первая программа на C++ "Hello World", только вместо "Hello World" вы выводите слова из подсказки. Ну и обычно приводят пример кода - того что вы делали, и вопрос о том что у вас не получилось.

Comment: @vegorov может текст в консольке надо раскрасить))

Comment: Сейчас учим escape -последовательности ! Это связано с этим заданием

Comment: @5grrthrthrh ага, `\t` и `\n`.

Comment: А где найти его на английском :?

Comment: [Каждый Охотник Желает Знать, Где Сидит Фазан.](http://langs.pro/publications/111/)

Comment: У нас [тут все-таки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) сайт для вопросов по программированию, а не по литературе. Стих надо гуглить, либо спрашивать где-то еще. "красиво оформить" - это ж субъективно. Опишите что конкретно вы хотите получить. Желательно показать, какой код у вас уже есть.

Comment: Связанные вопросы на Питоне: [Рисунок в консоле на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/836842/23044) 
и 
[Python. Вывод текста по середине терминала](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/518707/23044)

Answer (score 2):

every hunter wants to know where does pheasant sit

Каждый охотник желает знать где сидит фазан

1. Каждый - Красный
2. Охотник - Оранжевый
3. Желает - Жёлтый
4. Знать - Зелёный
5. Где - Голубой
6. Сидит - Синий
7. Фазан - Фиолетовый

Последовательность цветов в спектре (а так же - в радуге)

Цвет текста при выдаче в консоль задаёnся специальными ASCII последовательностями. Начинаются они с префикса CSI. Совокупность символов ESC и [ называют CSI или Control Sequence Introducer.

Существует очень много управляющих последовательностей. Для управления цветами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Команда установки цвета текста и фона имеет следующий вид:

```
CSI n1;n2m
```

Где n1 и n2 - числа, задающие код цвета текста и фона.

Цвет текста: 30 + n  из таблицы цветов

Цвет фона:   40 + n  из таблицы цветов

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << "Every" << "\n";
cout << "\tHunter" << "\n";
cout << "\t\tWants" << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\tTo know" << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t Where" << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\tDoes Pheasant" << "\n";
cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSit" << "\n\n";
```