# возможноли вывести картинку в консоль в языке си?

Tags: c

Как вывести картинку в консоль и возможно ли это?

Comment: В консоль - это как? Из цветных буковок?

Comment: Libcaca для цветных буков

Comment: Хотя тут скорее переключение в графику как на бэйсике имеется ввиду

Comment: Очень много вопросов: какая ОС? Что из себя представляет терминал (консоль)? Хотите ли вы сделать это портабельным? Что такое *картинка* в вашем понимании: ASCII art (`libcaca`, `aalib`)  или настоящая графика (`directfb`)?

Comment: Видели , когда включается bios - на мониторе, который находится в текстовом режиме рисуется лого energy star? Знаете как это сделано? Все элементарно: символы букв, попиксельно перерисовываются так, чтобы находясь рядом образовать картинку, как пазл, заменяютя символы текста в памяти на вновь сгенерированные и выводятся на экран как будто это текст.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Эх, ностальгия :) Под DOS'ом таким образом красивые бегущие строки делались, например - перешивая в памяти таблицу символов... Только для серьезной графики это не годится :(

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, откуда такая информация?

Comment: @Harry да тогда не было этих ваших интернетов, а еще я не забыл свой фидо-шный адрес, оттуда была и эта информация почерпнута

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  Ну почему "ваших"? Я сам в фидо был на протяжении почти 22 лет, с 1993 года...

Comment: @Harry это я так, для красного словца :) у меня был обычный поинт, 2:5030/588.20, но примерно году в 2004 в Питере появился ADSL и фидо отсохло.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Ну, если с пойнтом - тогда 22 полных точно будет :)

Comment: @Harry Помню эху ru.pictures.pseudo.graph, очень увлекательно

Comment: @Harry у меня отважный коллега с работы года до 10 тоже ноду держал

Comment: спасибо большое,а возможно вывести например какую нибудь png картинку целиком?)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460297/130

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Так](https://ideone.com/TafDhF) устроит?

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    puts("█▀█░░█░█░█▀█░█▀█░█░░░█░█▀▄▀█");
    puts("█░▄░░█▀█░█░█░█▀▄░█▀█░█░█░█░█");
    puts("▀▀▀░░▀░▀░▀▀▀░▀▀▀░▀▀▀░▀░▀░░░▀");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░█▀▀░█▀█░░█▀█░░█▀█░█▀▄▀█░░█░");
    puts("░█░░░█░█░░█░█░░█░█░█░█░█░░▀░");
    puts("░▀░░░▀▀▀░█▀▀▀█░▀▀▀░▀░░░▀░░▀░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░░░▄██▄░░░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░▄██████▄░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░▄████░█████▄░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░▄█████████░████░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░▄██░█████▄░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░▄████████████▄░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░▄███░███████░████▄░░░░░");
    puts("░░░▄████████░███████████▄░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░▄█████████░████▄░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░▄████░█████████░███▄░░░░");
    puts("░░▄██████████░███████████▄░░");
    puts("▄█████░█████████████░██████▄");
    puts("▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀████▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░░░████░░░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░");
    puts("░░█▀▀▀█░█▀▀▀▀█░█▀▀▀█░█▀▀▀▀█░");
    puts("░░█▄█░█░█░██░█░█▄█░█░█░██░█░");
    puts("░░█░▄██░█░██░█░█░▄██░█░██░█░");
    puts("░░█▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄█░█▄▄▄▄█░");
}
```

Comment: На телефоне виден только мусор.

Comment: спасибо большое,а возможно вывести например какую нибудь png картинку целиком?)

Comment: В общем случае - нет. В рамках стандарта - нет. И вообще, представьте себе консоль, работающую на чисто текстовом мониторе (представьте себе, такие тоже были :)) - и как вы тут что-то графическое выведите вообще?...